# Read Bmp Greyscales into C

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, bmp, grayscale

I looked for how to read a Bmp file into a 2 or 1 dimensional Array under C , there are many solutions but not the one i need.
I need to read the Black and white bmp into (to beginn) 2 dimensional array which have to contain values from 0 to 255 (greyscale)
and then transform it to 1 dimensional array(but that's not a problem).
Matlab does this automticly but i want to be more autonomous working under C/C++
at the end the bmp shall be saved into a Postgre Database int array.
Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia article about BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)? It explains the BMP file format very well, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bmp loader which I made for another SO question:
http://nishi.dreamhosters.com/u/so_bmp_v0.zip 
The example bmp there is RGB, but it seems to work with grayscale as well.

```
FILE* f = fopen( "winnt.bmp", "rb" ); if( f==0 ) return 1;
fread( buf, 1,sizeof(buf), f );
fclose(f);

BITMAPFILEHEADER& bfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER&)buf[0];
BITMAPINFO& bi = (BITMAPINFO&)buf[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];
BITMAPINFOHEADER& bih = bi.bmiHeader; 
char* bitmap = &buf[bfh.bfOffBits];
int SX=bih.biWidth, SY=bih.biHeight;
```

*bitmap* here is the pointer to the pixel table (should be made unsigned
for proper access though). Note that pixel rows in bmp can be stored in
reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, misread question :/
<s>If you don't mind "twisting" the rules a tiny little bit</s>

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int data[100][30] = {{0}}; /* initialize 2D array to all zeroes */
  int *p1d;
  size_t index;

  data[42][20] = 42; /* set 1 element ot 42 */
  p1d = &data[0][0];
  index = 42*30 + 20;
  printf("%d (should be 42)\n", p1d[index]); /* pretend it's a 1D array */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this code can help me, my problem is getting the right geryscales while reading the Bmp , but until now i've got values between 0 ans 255 but not the same as the ones i see in Matlab Matrix.